# Storing session data in controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I'm new to Spring. I'm working on a MVC application that would works as follows:

1) user fills the form with data necessary to create the connection to some service

2) controller gets the data from input, create new object serviceManager and save this object e.g in some HashMap with serviceId

3) next time user wants to use this service, controller using serviceId reads data from HashMap.

So I simply need to store this HashMap throughout the whole session in my controller for future use. What would be the best way to accomplish that? Maybe creating serviceManager object each time and reading data from database is the proper solution? In my controller I'm already using @Autowired fields which perfectly serve the purpose, but they're defined in spring xml and I have to store the data dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems your requirement is kind of same with mine which I should keep the main data in the session and every time get the detail data from client and combine 2 kind of data to retrieve something from database.  I just put the main part data in the session and then in the whole session that I can get it. I also try to use @SessionAttribute, but after tried dozens of time, I gave it up, it has a lots of problems. So if you can, I just recomment you to store the data in session, that's the samplest way.

Answer (score -1):

I'm newish to spring myself, but as far as putting this in the session:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"myObject"})
public class MyController() {
...
    @RequestMapping(value="/foo")
// Corrected as per Costi below
//    public String someMethod(@PathVariable MyObject myObject) {
    public String someMethod(@ModelAttribute MyObject myObject) {
    ...
    }
}
```

@SessionAttributes will put a MyObject named myObject into the session, if it's not already there, and the @PathVariable pulls it down so you can use it in the method.

The curlys in session attributes aren't necessary for just one attribute, however, you can specify more than one, comma separated, when you use the array notation (which is to say: the curlys)

Comment: The `@PathVariable` only "pulls down" path variables: segments of the URL path. You should use `@ModelAttribute("myObject")` instead.